# Qual é o propósito de um parêntesis vazio "()" numa expressão regular?

Tags: regex

Pesquisando no Stackoverlow Inglês sobre expressões regulares, deparei-me com uma determinada expressão onde apresenta na mesma um grupo vazio (uma expressão entre parênteses vazia).

Assim:

```
(DE)()([0-9]{1,12})
```

Qual é o propósito dessa "grupo vazio" (`()`) numa expressão regular?

Comment: Pelo pouco que sei, (regex é enorme) não faz sentido algum na expressão q vc postou.

Comment: Muita coisa em expressão regular não faz sentido para mim (porque não entendo para que serve). Mas que tem um propósito tem, senão não seria possível fazê-lo.

Comment: costumo testar as que faço em "testadores" online, não fez diferença com ou sem. vou olhar com mais cuidado para poder ajudar lhe.

fonte de estudo: http://aurelio.net/regex/guia/

Comment: @WallaceMaxters se esqueceu desta? ou ainda desejas uma resposta melhor?

Comment: @GuilhermeLautert acho que talvez caiba apenas uma edição explicando em que caso seria útil. (se você me disser que usar um grupo vazio não é útil em caso nenhum, marco imediatamente).

Answer (score 14):

Dependendo do caso apenas confundir quem está lendo a regex. Parêntesis indicam captura de grupo, então na expressão `(DE)()([0-9]{1,12})` `DE` vai ser capturado no primeiro grupo, no segundo vamos capturar nada e no terceiro `[0-9]{1,12}`, sendo que cada grupo pode ser referenciado por `$numerodogrupo` (na verdade depende da regex engine, algumas não usam cifrão), então temos três grupos: $1, $2 e $3. Exemplo prático, inverter o texto `DE25324534` usando a regex que você passou:

```js
var str = 'DE25324534';
var inverted = str.replace(/(DE)()([0-9]{1,12})/, '$3$1$2');
document.write(inverted);
```

O que ocorre aí é que a string original é substituída por $3 (os digitos) seguida pelo grupo $1 (DE), seguida pelo grupo $2 (não tem nada dentro), assim você pode ver que () solto na regex serve para absolutamente nada *neste caso*, contudo pode fazer sentido em algumas situações como mostrado na resposta do [Guilherme Lautert](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/111318/21328).

Comment: Não se deve julgar algo pelo primeira abstração que se vê. Esse "serve para absolutamente nada", é muito relativo.

Comment: @GuilhermeLautert também concordo. Na pergunta que vi no SOEN, me pareceu relativo a algo como : "Se eu substituir a regex, não precisarei substituir a ordem da captura de grupos. Basta colocar um grupo vazio, para que a contagem dos grupos fiquem semelhantes na substituição"

Comment: @WallaceMaxters eu montei um exemplo assim, mas esta muito feio, to tentando melhorar '-'

Answer (score 7):

A priori, nenhum.

Parênteses normalmente são usados para identificar grupos. Grupos, por sua vez, são usados para operações como extração de informações específicas ou localização de áreas para substituição da cadeia de caracteres considerado.

Neste seu caso, o motor de expressão regular apenas criará um grupo vazio, que sequer pode ser localizado.

Comment: Este resposta esta de acordo com o que o grupo representa, "um grupo vazio, que sequer pode ser localizado. ", a implementação vai depender do programador.

Answer (score 6):

Complementando a [Resposta do Cigano](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/111310/qual-%C3%A9-o-prop%C3%B3sito-de-um-par%C3%AAntesis-vazio-numa-express%C3%A3o-regular#answer-111314).

Grupo são usado para extração de informação ou reutilização.
Um grupo `()` vazio faz referencia ao *nada* que em compiladore seria o mesmo que uma transição direta para o próximo estagio.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

#### Exemplo (ruim, mas demostrativo)

```
var replace = '$1$3$5';

'2016/02/02'.replace(/(\d{4})(\/)(\d{2})(\/)(\d{2})/, replace); // 20160202
'2016-02-02'.replace(/(\d{4})(-)(\d{2})(-)(\d{2})/, replace);   // 20160202
'20160202'.replace(/(\d{4})()(\d{2})()(\d{2})/, replace);       // 20160202
```

Comment: upvote. Ótimo exemplo e realmente faz sentido tanto na base teórica em finite automaton quanto na utilidade prática. Editei minha resposta para não generalizar tanto e para referenciar a sua.

Comment: Ah, então a ideia é ter uma sequência onde a parametrização é prevista de uma determinada forma. Ou seja, usa-se o grupo vazio para poder forçar o parâmetro com o valor desejado, independente da sequência na regex (podia apenas ter colocado isso na resposta :p)

Comment: @WallaceMaxters é esse exemplo não foi dos melhores, mas sim seria isso.

Answer (score 1):

Acredito que você tenha visto [esta pergunta](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25623682) (pelo menos é a mesma regex), e lá também são listados alguns possíveis usos para este recurso (que explico com mais detalhes abaixo).

Vale lembrar que, como já dito nas outras respostas, **na expressão específica que você colocou, sem nenhum contexto adicional**, esses parênteses realmente não servem para nada.

---

Mas dependendo do contexto, ele pode ter seus usos. Lembrando que [um par de parênteses cria um grupo de captura](https://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html), que fará parte do *match* retornado. Mesmo que não tenha nada dentro dele, será criado um grupo contendo "nada" (o que na maioria das implementações - senão em todas - resulta em uma string vazia).

E quando isso seria útil? Bem, imagine um caso em que tenho uma função que recebe o *match* de uma regex e usa somente os grupos 1 e 3 (exemplos em Python, mas poderia ser em qualquer outra linguagem que suporte grupos de captura):

```py
def faz_algo(match):
    g1 = match.group(1)
    g3 = match.group(3)
    # ... faz algo com os grupos 1 e 3 (os demais são ignorados)

import re

match = re.match(r'([a-z]+)(\d+)([a-z]+)', 'abc123xyz')
if match:
    faz_algo(match)
```

No exemplo acima, estou criando três grupos: um com letras, outro com dígitos, e outro com letras. Na função `faz_algo`, pego somente os grupos 1 e 3 (no caso, eles serão respectivamente `abc` e `xyz`).

Agora vamos supor que tenho um caso em que quero reaproveitar a função `faz_algo`, mas agora eu preciso pegar `abc` e `123`. Neste caso, eu mudaria a regex para:

```py
match = re.match(r'([a-z]+)()(\d+)', 'abc123xyz')
```

Ou seja, agora o grupo 1 são as letras (`abc`), o grupo 2 é vazio, e o grupo 3 são os números (`123`). Desta forma, não preciso mudar a função `faz_algo`, pois ela continua pegando os grupos 1 e 3. Eu só preciso ajustar a regex para que estes grupos contenham o que eu preciso.

<sup>Claro que eu poderia criar outra função que verifica os grupos do *match* e refatorar `faz_algo` para receber os valores como parâmetros, em vez de sempre buscar grupos fixos. Mas pode ser que eu não possa modificar a função `faz_algo` (por exemplo, ela é de uma dependência externa, etc). Enfim, esta é uma situação na qual um grupo vazio seria útil (embora admito que seja uma "solução de elegância questionável").</sup>

---

Outro uso "esotérico" é que um grupo vazio pode ser usado como um "marcador": uma indicação de que a regex "passou" pode determinado ponto.

Vamos supor que tenho vários números sendo lidos de algum lugar, e eu quero verificar quais contém 4 dígitos, mas somente os dígitos de 1 a 4, e todos os dígitos são diferentes (ou seja, `1234` e `3241` são ok, mas `1123`, `3333` e `1235` não). **Eu sei que dá para resolver de maneira mais fácil sem regex**, mas com regex uma opção seria:

```py
import re

r = re.compile(r'^(?:1()|2()|3()|4()){4}\1\2\3\4$')
for n in range(1000000):
    if r.match(str(n)):
        print(n)
```

Ela é bem confusa e complexa, mas basicamente: `(?:1()|2()|3()|4())` é um [grupo de não-captura](https://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html#noncap) (indicado por `(?:`), ou seja, o primeiro parênteses não cria um grupo. Dentro dele temos uma [alternância](https://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html) com quatro opções: os dígitos de 1 a 4.

Repare que depois de cada dígito tem um grupo vazio. E eles servem apenas para indicar que a regex passou por ali. Ou seja, se ela encontrar um dígito `1`, o grupo 1 estará setado (ele conterá a string vazia, mas o que importa é que estará setado no *match*). O mesmo vale para os outros dígitos: se os quatro grupos estiverem setados, quer dizer que tem pelo menos um digito de cada na string.

A seguir, eu coloco o quantificador `{4}` para indicar que quero 4 dígitos. Note que aqui eu ainda não garanti a unicidade (a string poderia ser, por exemplo, `1122` - e neste caso somente os grupos 1 e 2 estariam setados).

E como eu faço para garantir que os 4 grupos estão setados? Eu uso as [*back-references*](https://www.regular-expressions.info/backref.html): no caso, `\1` refere-se ao grupo 1, `\2` ao grupo 2, etc. Como os grupos são vazios, então os valores das *back-references* serão strings vazias, mas somente se os respectivos grupos estiverem setados.

Ou seja, se algum grupo não estiver setado, a *back-reference* também não estará, e a regex não encontrará um *match*. Por exemplo, se o número for `1124`, o grupo 3 não estará setado, e portanto `\3` também não. Então a regex falha, pois ela tenta procurar por `\3`.

Se todos os grupos estiverem setados, indica que todos os dígitos de 1 a 4 estão presentes na string - e o quantificador `{4}` garante que a string tem somente 4 dígitos (e como os grupos são strings vazias, então `\1\2\3\4` não interfere no tamanho da string sendo procurada; lembre-se que os grupos estão aí somente para verificar se o respectivo dígito foi encontrado). Aliás, como os grupos são strings vazias, tanto faz a ordem que eu coloco as *back-references* (lembre-se: elas só estão ali para verificar se o grupo foi setado).

Sim, é *overkill*. Sim, tem jeitos mais fáceis de verificar isso sem regex. Mas enfim, isso seria um uso para grupos de captura vazios.