# O que faz detalhadamente a expressão regular "/(?=(?:...)*$)/"?

Tags: javascript, regex

Precisei a pouco tempo de uma solução para colocar pontos para separar números de três em três, de trás para frente.

Por exemplo:

```
1000 => 1.000
100000 => 100.000
10000000 => 1.000.000
```

Em uma resposta que encontrei [no Stackoverflow Inglês](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14751905/3096922), a solução passada foi usar essa expressão regular:

```js
function separarDeTresEmTres(numero)
{
  return String(numero).split(/(?=(?:...)*$)/ ).join('.');
}


console.log(separarDeTresEmTres(1000));  
console.log(separarDeTresEmTres(1000000));
console.log(separarDeTresEmTres(10000000));
```

Mas eu não entendi muito bem qual foi a mágica feita por `/(?=(?:...)*$)/`.

O que está fazendo com que essa expressão regular separe os números de três em três, de trás para frente? Qual é a explicação?

**NOTA**: Eu não quero respostas explicando como se separa um número de três em três, até porque a expressão regular que estou usando já está fazendo isso. A pergunta aqui é especificamente sobre como funciona cada parte dessa expressão regular. Eu não quero a solução do problema sem a explicação do que está acontecendo.

Comment: Geralmente utilizo essa ferramenta para tirar dúvidas: https://regex101.com/ talvez ajude em algo.

Comment: @FilipeMoraes boa dica, vou dar uma olhada agora!

Comment: "*Em uma resposta que encontrei no Stackoverflow Inglês*" - Poderia colocar o link?

Comment: @VictorStafusa editado :p

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Bem, vamos construir essa expressão regular:

- `.` - Reconhece um caractere qualquer.
- `...` - Reconhece três caracteres quaisquer.
- `(?:...)` - Grupo sem captura de três caracteres quaisquer. Grupos sem captura são começados por `(?:` e terminados por `)`.
- `(?:...)*` - Repetição. Essa `*` indica 0 ou mais repetições. Portanto isso são vários grupos de três caracteres.
- `$` - Final da string. Ao garantir que o final da string está presente, garante-se que nenhum caractere pode ficar sobrando no final.
- `(?:...)*$` - Grupos de três caracteres seguidos do final da string. Isso garante que os grupos reconhecidos devem estar no final da string, e não no começo.
- `(?=(?:...)*$)` - *Lookahead* positivo - Força o reconhecimento do que se segue e procura todos os locais onde a expressão seguinte coincide com alguma coisa.

Para entender esse último ponto, vamos supor que a expressão fosse `(?=a(?:...)*$)` e a cadeia de entrada fosse `1234a567890`. Neste caso, o valor reconhecido na expressão interna ao `(?=`-`)` seria o `a567890`, pois isso seria um `a` seguido de um número de caracteres múltiplo de 3, mas o reconhecimento de toda a cadeia capturada pelo *lookahead* positivo (no caso a entrada completa) é forçado mesmo assim. Observe que o reconhecimento do todo aconteceu mesmo que o começo da string seguinte não tenha entrado na parte reconhecida - isso é o que o *lookahead* positivo faz. O reconhecimento também ocorre várias vezes porque a regex dentro do `(?=`-`)` é reconhecida em vários locais diferentes - cada cadeia de tamanho múltiplo de três caracteres presas no final da string (inclusive 0) precedida por qualquer coisa é reconhecida.

- O `/` antes e depois da regex é o que o Javascript usa para denotar e delimitar a regex.
- O `String(numero)` é uma forma de converter um número em uma string.
- O método `split` pica a cadeia de caracteres onde o reconhecimento ocorre, de forma que ela vai acabar fatiando a string de três em três caracteres do final para o começo porque várias possibilidades diferentes foram reconhecidas e criar com isso um array de strings.
- O `join` é um método do array que junta todos os pedaços em uma só string colocando um separador entre cada pedaço, o resultado disso é retornado com o `return`.

Comment: Victor, ótima resposta, cara +1

Answer (score 20):

Vamos por parte:

```
/(?=(?:...)*$)/
```

- `?=` Vai capturar o espaço seguido da expressão após o =.
- `?:` Define toda a expressão dentro dos parênteses em um grupo de não captura.
- `...` Qualquer caractere 3 vezes.
- `*$` Repetindo várias vezes no final da string.

Explicando na prática:

O que acontece é o seguinte, essa expressão agrupa 3 caracteres: `(?:...)`, e faz a captura antes deles: `?=`, o que garante que isso seja feito de trás pra frente infinitas vezes é o: `*$`, aplicando o split o número 1000000 ficaria dividido assim: 1|000|000, depois é só ele juntar com um ponto `.join('.')` que a mágica está feita.

OBS.: O grupo de não captura `?:` serve para não atrapalhar na hora de capturar o que realmente importa, que é antes dos 3 caracteres.

Comment: Ótimo, isso sim responde a pergunta. +1

Comment: Espero que tenha ficado claro, é meio complicado explicar isso, se tiver alguma dúvida que eu consiga responder, estamos ai!

Answer (score 9):

Esta REGEX é bem interessante pois combina alguns fatores interessantes.

#### Fatores

- Sabemos que REGEX se usa para **capturar** determinado conteúdo de um texto/string.
- Sabemos também que split **divide pela ocorrência**.

#### Exemplos

```js
var test = 'Teste de captura';
var r = /c.p/
console.log(test.match(r));
```

```js
var test = 'Teste de divisão';
var div = 'e';
console.log(test.split(div));
```

Note que no `split` o caractere de divisão se perdeu.

#### O que está acontecendo?

Esta função está unindo estas duas particularidades.
A grande questão é: **"o que ele está usando para capturar e dividir"**?
A resposta é : **O "*nada*"**.

Agora você deve estar se perguntando "Como assim o nada?"

#### O que é o *"nada"*

[Nesta resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/111318/14213) eu abordo um pouco o que é o ***nada***.

> em compiladores seria o mesmo que uma transição direta para o próximo estágio

#### Como ele faz isso

Através da parte da REGEX `(?= )`. Isso cria uma captura que não deve ir para o resultado.

#### Explicação Geral da REGEX

- `$` como você definiu um fim, isso vai alterar o comportamento padrão da REGEX e fazer ela "iniciar" pelo fim, casando o conteúdo de traz para frente.
- `(?: )*` - Só diz que é um grupo que pode se repetir infinitamente, mas não deve ser contado.
- `(?= )` - É um captura que deve ocorrer mas não ir para o resultado.
- `...` - Sequencia de 3 caracteres quais quer.

#### E onde está o *nada* nisso tudo?

No fato que você não tem uma captura, você tem uma sequencia de 3 caracteres que vai do fim ao inicio. E ele esta dividindo pela ***transição*** para o próximo estagio de 3. Seria a lacuna entre os dois.

Answer (score -2):

Já agora uma variante da mesma ideia, usando a mesma filosofia -- desta vez um simples substitute em Perl (para realçar que esta questão é ortogonal à linguagem de programação)

```
$ echo "1000 e mais 100000 10000000" |
      perl -pe 's/\d(?=(\d\d\d)+\b)/$&./g'
1.000 e mais 100.000 10.000.000
```

Ou seja: um digito "d" seguido de grupos de 3 digitos, é substituído por "d." Como habitualmente:

- `\b` : fronteira de palavra
- `\d`  : dígito
- `(?= regexp)` : zero-width lookahead (contexto direito)
- `s/regexp/string/g` : find-replace global
- `$&` :  a string que fez matching

Já apora, aplicando directamente ao caso (mais simples) da pergunta, em javascript ficaria:

```
function separarDeTresEmTres(numero)
{
  return String(numero).replace(/\d(?=(...)+$)/g,"$&.");
}
```

Comment: -1 isso não responde ao que foi perguntado.