# Como separar números de três em três, de trás para frente, em JavaScript, sem expressão regular?

Tags: javascript, string, formatação, números

Eu já sei como [separar os números de três em três, de trás para frente, com expressão regular em JavaScript](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/182287/o-que-faz-detalhadamente-a-express%C3%A3o-regular).

Mas gostaria de saber se em JavaScript existe uma solução mais simples, e sem o uso de expressão regular.

Por exemplo:

```
1000; // 1.000
10000; // 10.000
10000000; // 10.000.000
```

Como eu poderia fazer isso?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

O [`toLocaleString()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toLocaleString) faz isto.

```js
function separarDeTresEmTres(numero) {
    return numero.toLocaleString();
}
console.log(separarDeTresEmTres(1000));  
console.log(separarDeTresEmTres(1000000));
console.log(separarDeTresEmTres(10000000));
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/JavaScript/String/LocaleNumber.js).

Comment: Sério mesmo? Estou com vergonha de ter usado uma expressão regular agora :p

Answer (score 4):

Na "unha", eu criei essa função que converte o número em *String* para poder percorrer os elementos, e então usar o [substring](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring) para ir *cortando* e montando de três em três.

```js
var n1 = 1000; // 1.000
var n2 = 10000; // 10.000
var n3 = 100000; // 100.000
var n4 = 1000000; // 1.000.000
var n5 = 10000000; // 10.000.000


function formatarTresEmTres(n) {
  n = n.toString();
  var nFormatado = '';
  for (var i = n.length; i > 0; i = i - 3) {
    nFormatado += '.' + n.substring(i - 3, i);
  };
  return nFormatado.split(".").slice(1).reverse().join(".");
}

console.log(formatarTresEmTres(n1), formatarTresEmTres(n2), formatarTresEmTres(n3), formatarTresEmTres(n4),  formatarTresEmTres(n5));
```