# Formatar moeda com separador de milhar

Tags: javascript

Tenho o seguinte código:

```
function numberParaReal(numero){
    var formatado = "R$ " + numero.toFixed(2).replace(".",",");
    return formatado;
}

function realParaNumber(texto){
    var compativelComParseFloat = texto.replace("R$ ","");
    compativelComParseFloat = compativelComParseFloat.replace(",",".");
    var valor = parseFloat(compativelComParseFloat);
    return valor;
}
```

Porem ele só exibe valores nesse formato: 1000,00.

Queria deixar assim: 1.000,00 ~ 100.000,00 ~ 10.000.000,00 e assim vai...

Seria alguma coisa como 3 casas antes da vírgula recebe ponto, só não sei como fazer isso.

Provavelmente devem existir funções prontas para este tipo de situação, porém como estou aprendendo, não seria o ideal eu utilizar de funções prontas.

Answer (score 46):

Você pode usar a função [toLocaleString()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toLocaleString), que é parte do protótipo do Number. Por exemplo, para converter 124231.45 e 1242311234.45 para o padrão brasileiro, use, respectivamente:

```
(124231.45).toLocaleString('pt-BR'); // => "124.231,45"

(1242311234.45).toLocaleString('pt-BR'); // => "1.242.311.234,45"
```

Comment: Que maneiro cara, não conhecia esse método. Muito bom +1.

Comment: @JuniorNunes eu acho muito legal. Tem até um argumento que adiciona R$ à string: `(1231230123.23).toLocaleString('pt-BR', { style: 'currency', currency: 'BRL' }); // => 
"R$1.231.230.123,23"`

Comment: Só funciona para situações que você tenha valores após a virgula. caso o valor informado, por exemplo seja 1000 o retorno é 1.000 e não 1.000,00 como esperado.

Answer (score 36):

Usando o seu código fiz algumas modificações:

```js
function numberToReal(numero) {
    var numero = numero.toFixed(2).split('.');
    numero[0] = "R$ " + numero[0].split(/(?=(?:...)*$)/).join('.');
    return numero.join(',');
}

var x = numberToReal(9999000.33);
console.log(x);

var y = numberToReal(100000);
console.log(y);

var z = numberToReal(10.50);
console.log(z);
```

O que eu faço é o seguinte:

Primeiro pego o número e fixo ele com 2 casas decimais e separo a string em um array de 2 partes (antes e depois do ponto).

```
var numero = numero.toFixed(2).split('.');
// Se o número inicial for 100.00, numero[0] será 100 e numero[1] será 00
```

Dessa forma na segunda linha eu posso trabalhar o número excluindo as casas decimais (`numero[0]`), o que o split, o regex e o join fazem nessa parte eu explico [nessa resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/182300/57573).

```
numero[0] = "R$ " + numero[0].split(/(?=(?:...)*$)/).join('.');
```

Depois é só retornar o número formatado juntando com as casas decimais usando a virgula.

```
return numero.join(',');
```

Comment: Muito legal, era isso que eu queria, porem tem algum nome técnico sobre isso aqui  --> (/(?=(?:...)*$)/) <-- queria um nome técnico pra pesquisar sobre isso e aprender tudo.

Comment: @NicolasGuilherme tem sim amigo, o nome disso é Expressão regular ou regex, você pode ler mais sobre expressões regulares no javascript [aqui](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions), mas lembrando que existem muitas outras linguagens que fazem uso do regex.

Answer (score 7):

Eu uso esse polyfill nos meus projetos.

ele cria um método que você pode utilizar em todas as suas variáveis que são do tipo `Number`
Recebe como parametros:

1. Número de casas decimais
2. O simbolo que você deseja usar
3. O simbolo usado para separar as milhares
4. O simbolo usado para separar as decimais

Ex:

```
var numero = 123456.78;
numero.formatMoney(2, "R$ ", ".", ",");
```

Acredito que possa te ajudar.

```js
Number.prototype.formatMoney = function(places, symbol, thousand, decimal) {
 places = !isNaN(places = Math.abs(places)) ? places : 2;
 symbol = symbol !== undefined ? symbol : "$";
 thousand = thousand || ",";
 decimal = decimal || ".";
 var number = this, 
     negative = number < 0 ? "-" : "",
     i = parseInt(number = Math.abs(+number || 0).toFixed(places), 10) + "",
     j = (j = i.length) > 3 ? j % 3 : 0;
 return symbol + negative + (j ? i.substr(0, j) + thousand : "") + i.substr(j).replace(/(\d{3})(?=\d)/g, "$1" + thousand) + (places ? decimal + Math.abs(number - i).toFixed(places).slice(2) : "");
};

// Aqui para testar
var a = 3211000.354;

document.getElementById('testP').innerHTML = a.formatMoney(2, "R$ ", ".", ",");
```

```html
<p id="testP"></p>
```

Comment: Tem como utilizar sem arredondar, tipo 1.200,00 - 3,46 = 1.196,54 em vez disso ele me mostra 1.196,60... valeu..

Comment: @UlissesGimenes da um exemplo de como voce esta usando, eu faria a conta antes de mostrar o valor. Ex. `var valor = 1200 - 3.46; a.formatMoney(2, "R$ ", ".", ",")`

Comment: É a forma que estou utilizando, mas parece que agora está calculando corretamente, acho que era valor de cache do navegador