# Trocar Botão por Auto soma

Tags: javascript

Como eu troco o botão `calcular` por auto soma com javascript !

[Exemplo] ao digitar no `input name="campo1"` ele soma com o `input name="campo2"` automaticamente sem precisar do botão `calcular`

é um simulador de moedas pois quero por o `R$` no `input name="campo1"` e assim quando eu por o dinheiro ele vai me dar o valor na mesma hora no `input name="campo2"`

Obs: o `input name="campo2"`está multiplicando por `23` e `25` eu só quero deixar auto soma para tirar o botão `calcular`

este é o código :
 SCRIPT :

```
    <script>
function soma() 
{
    var valor;
    var campo = form.campo1.value;
    if(campo >=1  && campo < 99){
        valor=23;
    }else{
        valor=25;
    }

    form.campo4.value = parseInt(campo) * parseInt(valor) 
}
</script>
```

HTML :

```
    <form name="form">
<input name="campo1" id="demo4"><br> 
<input name="campo2" value="" id="demo3" style="display: none;"><br>  
<input name="campo4" readonly id="resultado"><br>
<input type="button" onclick="soma()" value="CALCULAR">
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para ter um código a ser interpretado quando digita pode utilizar o evento [keyup](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/keyup) que pode escutar diretamente na etiqueta html:

```
<input name="campo1" id="demo4" onkeyup="soma()"><br>
```

Exemplo:

```js
function soma() 
{
    var valor;
    var campo = form.campo1.value;
    if(campo >=1  && campo < 99){
        valor=23;
    }else{
        valor=25;
    }

    form.campo4.value = parseInt(campo) * parseInt(valor) 
}
```

```html
<form name="form">
<input name="campo1" id="demo4" onkeyup="soma()"><br> 
<input name="campo2" value="" id="demo3" style="display: none;"><br>  
<input name="campo4" readonly id="resultado"><br>
</form>
```

Melhor até seria fazer a ligação ao evento totalmente por javascript com:

```
document.getElementById("demo4").addEventListener("keyup", soma));
```

Comment: Obrigado Isac ! sabe como eu limito também o max de numero tipo 3 antes da , e 2 depois da , ??

Comment: @AndreJunior Se está a falar de formatação de moeda, já tem várias perguntas para isso, tais como [esta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/188190/formatar-moeda-com-separador-de-milhar)

Comment: Obrigado de novo  me ajudou muito !

Comment: @AndreJunior De nada, fico contente de ter ajudado.

Answer (score 0):

Aqui fica uma sugestão, enviando o valor inserido diretamente no `onkeyup`aqui:

```
<input name="campo1" id="demo4" onkeyup="soma(Number(this.value))">
```

```js
var resultado = document.getElementById('resultado');
function soma(valor) {
  var multiplicador = valor >= 1 && valor < 99 ? 23 : 25;
  resultado.value = multiplicador * valor;
}
```

```html
<form name="form">
  <input name="campo1" id="demo4" onkeyup="soma(Number(this.value))"><br>
  <input name="campo2" value="" id="demo3" style="display: none;"><br>
  <input name="campo4" readonly id="resultado"><br>
</form>
```