# Separar o conteúdo de uma váriavel via Regex

Tags: javascript, regex

Em 2 variáveis quero realizar as seguintes operações. Na 1ª, `var chat1`, separar via regex 4 informações: "**A:**", "**How are you?**", "**B:**" e "**I'm fine, thanks.**", e poder acessá-las pelos seus índices usando os grupos de captura. E na 2ª, `var chat2`, separar 2 informações: "**A:**" e "**How are you?**". Entendo pouco de regex e acabei não obtendo os resultados esperados.

```js
var chat1 = "A:How are you?B:I'm fine, thanks.";
var chat2 = "A:How are you?";

var c1 = chat1.match(/\b(A:)(.*?)(B:)(.*?)\b/i);
// c1[1] daria "A:", c1[2] daria "How are you?", c1[3] daria "B:" e c1[4] daria "I'm fine, thanks."
var c2 = chat2.match(/\b(A:)(.*?)\b/i);
// c2[1] daria "A:", c2[2] daria "How are you?"

console.log(c1);
// Resultado:
Array [ "A:How are you?B:", "A:", "How are you?", "B:", "" ]

console.log(c2);
// Resultado:
Array [ "A:", "A:", "" ]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você pode usar de uma forma mais simplificada, sem o `?`, `$` ou `\b`:

```
(A:)(.*)(B:)(.*)
```

Quando você usa o `?` no último grupo, terá que usar `$` para que ele saiba o fim da string. Portanto, se torna desnecessário se você usar apenas `.*` que irá capturar a string toda até o fim da linha.

```js
var chat1 = "A:How are you?B:I'm fine, thanks.";
var chat2 = "A:How are you?";

var c1 = chat1.match(/(A:)(.*)(B:)(.*)/i);
var c2 = chat2.match(/(A:)(.*)/i);
console.log(c1);
console.log(c2);
```

Comment: Tem como fazer com que case a expressão exata e nada mais? Ex: se `var c1` fosse `chat2.match(/(A:)(.*)/i)` não casaria, e vice-versa, se `var c2`fosse `chat1.match(/(A:)(.*)(B:)(.*)/i)` também não casaria.

Comment: No original as variáveis `chat1` e `chat2` são na verdade uma só variável (`var chat`), que poderá conter ambos os valores. O que acontece é que a expressão `.match(/(A:)(.*)/i)`, quando aplicada à variável `chat1` também retorna verdadeiro, incluindo **B:I'm fine, thanks.** (a resposta), indesejável. O que eu gostaria é que a expressão `.match(/(A:)(.*)/i)` só relacionasse caso a expressão fosse apenas **"A:How are you?"** (a pergunta) e não **"A:How are you?B:I'm fine, thanks."** (a pergunta e a resposta).

Comment: Não funcionou. O resultado dá nulo para ambas as expressões.

Comment: @eden Se o `A:` for sempre terminar em `?` (for sempre uma pergunta), talvez este ajude https://jsfiddle.net/o19n8824/2/  (tirei o `/i`, não sei se é necessário)

Comment: 1º Eu preciso que se mantenham os grupos de captura do jeito que estão para que eu possa usá-los individualmente depois; `(A:)` separado de `(.*)` e não junto do jeito que você colocou: `(A:.*)`. 2º Não quero que a regex `.match(/(A:)(.*)/i)` extraia a parte da pergunta, e sim que dê ***verdadeiro*** se casar a expressão inteira (**A:How are you?**) e ***falso/nulo*** caso ela contenha também a parte da resposta.

Comment: @eden Ao executar o snippet, veja que a array retorna os valores separados. Você pode usar eles pegando pelo índice.

Answer (score 0):

Basta adicionar o caractere **$** no final das expressões.

```js
var chat1 = "A:How are you?B:I'm fine, thanks.";
var regex = /\b(A:)(.*?)(B:)(.*?)$/i;
var resultado = chat1.match(regex);
console.log(resultado);
```

---

```js
var chat2 = "A:How are you?";
var regex = /\b(A:)(.*?)$/i;
var resultado = chat2.match(regex);
console.log(resultado);
```

#### Leitura recomendada:

- [O que faz detalhadamente a expressão regular “/(?=(?:…)*$)/”?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/182287)