# O que a expressão "/^(?:(?:gatos?|cachorro):)?/" faz?

Tags: regex

A dúvida é quanto a seguinte expressão regular:

```
/^(?:(?:gatos?|cachorro):)?/
```

Na compreensão tenho o seguinte:

- Início: `^`
- `( )`: isto aqui é um agrupamento, correto? tipo `(gato|cachorro|etc..)`?
- Porque o primeiro `(?`? - indica algo como "*Se existir `(`*"?
- No final, tem um bloco `()` com `?`. Será que é algo como se existir o bloco?

Comment: Essa regex me parece estranhas, o `(?:` significa que casa o padrão mas não captura ou seja é um grupo vazio. tem um `:`  perdido aqui => `):)?`. `?` no final significa caracter opcional, ou seja no grupo pode casar `gato` ou `gatos`. Tem um no final do grupo ...

Comment: Achei isto:http://regexr.com/ , testei com: "/(?:(?:gatos?|cachorro):)?/", e no campo do texto: digitei vários dados (gatos, gato, gato:, gatos:, outro dado, cachorro...etc), retirei o '^' do começo do search,também dá para testar usando o "grep" no terminal, só que tem que retirar os '/  /', e no caso do '(' colocar '\(', e '|', '\|', muito grato, tenho que estudar mais...

Answer (score 14):

Vamos explicar a regex:

- `/.../` - Essas `/` são usadas no Javascript para denotar que o que há dentro delas é uma regex. Assim sendo, a regex de verdade é o `^(?:(?:gatos?|cachorro):)?`.
- `^` - Início da string. Isso significa que o que quer que seja encontrado, tem que ser encontrado no início da string, não no meio dela.
- `(?: ... )` - É um grupo sem captura. É usado apenas para agrupar subexpressões. Regex permitem capturas com o `( ... )`, de forma que você possa extrair partes do texto que dê o *match*. O uso desse `?:` desabilita a captura quando você não tem interesse nisso ou quando isso pudesse bagunçar outras partes na qual você deseja que a captura seja feita. No seu caso, você não tem interesse em capturar partes, apenas o todo.
- `gatos?|cachorro` - Isso pode ser `gato` ou `gatos` ou `cachorro`. O `s?` significa que o `s` pode ou não aparecer. O `|` indica alternativas. O `(?: ... )` ao redor serve para agrupar isso tudo para que o `|` saiba onde começa e onde termina as alternativas.
- `:` (o último) - Significa o caractere `:` mesmo.
- O último `?` - significa que o que estiver antes no `(?: ... )` pode ou não aparecer. Se não aparecer, é dado match mesmo assim.

Desta forma, há apenas quatro strings que essa regex reconhece e que devem estar ancoradas no começo da string. São elas:

- (vazio)
- `gato:`
- `gatos:`
- `cachorro:`

É de se notar que o final da string não é verificado. Assim sendo, o uso de `gato:blabla` também dá um match. Mas como o início é verificado, `xgato:` não dá match.

Imagino que o contexto original disso seja algo assim:

```
\^(?:(?:https?|ftp):)?\
```

Ou seja, é algo que tem alguma relação com a verificação se uma parte de texto trata-se de um link (se começa com `http:`, `https:` ou `ftp:`). Entretanto, ele continua aceitando o caso de não haver nada disso por conta do último `?`.

Comment: Muito grato pela explicação, tenho que estudar mais...

Comment: O grupo sem captura na verdade é `(?: ... )` se não por o `:` [vai gerar um erro](https://regex101.com/r/NU6fij/1).

Comment: @GuilhermeLautert Eu havia esquecido de digitar o `:`. Editado. Obrigado pelo aviso.

Answer (score 6):

Sua regex parece procurar por um 'campo' na string no padrão:

```
gato:
gatos:
cachorro:
```

`(?:)` significa que sua regex deve casar com esse padrão porem a captura não vai para o grupo ou seja é um grupo sem captura.

`?` No final ela significa que a captura daquele caracter ou grupo é opcional como em: `gatos?` pode casar com `gato` ou `gatos`

**Relacionada:**

[Significado de ?: ?= ?! ?= ?! em uma regex](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/13598/91)

Comment: Muito obrigado à todos pela ajuda, vou dar uma pesquisada no link.

Comment: [Grupo vazio](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/111318/14213) não seria o termo correto, como eu comento em minha resposta, o grupo vazio faz referencia ao nada, creio que o mais correto seria "grupo não contável" apesar de fer feio.

Comment: Poderia falar tambem, "grupo sem captura", como mencionado na outra resposta

Comment: @GuilhermeLautert obrigado pela sugestão editei a resposta.